# Store virtual tables - best practice

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-design

I'm designing a database where I want to store multiple tables. The tables do not share the same structure. They can have any number of columns with any types that are allowed by the db engine.

I can think of two ways building up the database:
1.) storing the datatables as they are, in separate tables
2.) splitting them into virtual tables

If I choose 1.) I will have loads of tables in the database. By choosing 2.) I will have a managable number of tables for storing the data but I have to create massive joins to build up each datatable again.

What's the best practice if there can be any number (dozens or hundreds) of datatables? Are there other options?

edit: The database stores static data, the datatables are not related.

Comment: Don't use key-value (EAV) schema; it is a nightmare in multiple ways.  Don't have thousands of tables (hundreds is ok).  Normalize, but don't over-normalize.  Do not normalize "continuous" values, such as dates, prices, floats.

Comment: "massive joins" vs "datatables are not related" -- which is it?